# What is the German equivalent of “about” (as in “about this site”)

Tags: translation, english-to-german, preposition

I’m translating a website into German, even though I don’t know German. Anyway.

In English websites you often find the word **about** in the navigation section, or similarly in other applications; meaning *about this site* or *about this application*.

What would be a good German word for this usage?

The words I have looked up as candidates are: **um** and **über**. In Norwegian we would use something similar to *um: om*. Would that be the correct choice in German, too?

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, we are not a translation service. If you have checked dictionaries for possible phrasings and have an idea which one would be better or worse, we are glad to help you but we do not translate for you. In its current form, this question will get closed.

Comment: Is it a private website or a company's website? For a company's website you should get a translator or ask the company for translations. There are multiple phrases for your question. Maybe just check some German websites and check out the phrases used. I am sure you can then Google those phrases to get an idea.

Comment: Thanks for good advice. It's a small company with no budget for translation. But we'll get by ;)

Comment: German question about an alternative to the common translation: [Alternative für den Ausdruck “über mich”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/28785/1859)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You shouldn’t use *Über* by itself and probably not at all. In my opinion it’s an anglicism and sounds weird in German. Whenever I read this I always think that it was either translated literally from English by someone who doesn’t speak proper German or some hipster who wants his website to sound American and “cool” intentionally.

In my opinion you have **three choices:**

1. **Use Über with an object.** *Über diese Webseite* is OK. But are you really talking about the website itself and not actually about something the website was made for? For pages where you say something about a product, company or team use *Über unser(e) Produkt(e)*, *Über unsere Firma* or *Über unser Team* respectively.
2. Better just **use the noun describing what you are giving information about.** Just name the page *Unser Produkt*, *Unsere Firma*, *Unser Team* or simply *Produkt*, *Firma*, *Team*.
3. Use **Impressum** if the page contains formal information like contact address, phone number, the person responsible for the website and legal information. This is where most Germans would expect such content since an *Impressum* is mandatory for every German website subject to German laws and has to contain that type of information.

(German is my first language)

Comment: It actually does make perfect sense to just specify what the "about" is referring to. I guess I'm so used to seeing the word "About" all alone by itself on a web page footer, that I forgot to question it. Vielen dank @problemofficer.

Comment: Well, when "About" is alone, it means "About us/this" in general, so any kind of meta-information, and I wouldn't replace it by "us" or "this". Just the typically German usage (as in "Über unser Produkt") is IM-andalsoyour-O questionable.
Can't remember where I had seen "Über" alone, not sure how I feel about that... but it is as logical or useful as a generic "About" is.

Comment: „Über uns“ would be the shortest possible form.

Answer (score 11):

*About* in German is *über*.

*About this site* would be *über diese Seite*.

Comment: @Em1: I haven’t voted, but _Seite_ for _site_ (which may comprise lots of pages) is questionable, although I know it is sometimes used that way.

Comment: @chirlu, "über diese Seite" is unfortunately quite common, despite being wrong. It's simply one of the false friends that keep copied over and over.

Comment: So what IS the German word for website? I have only an old dictionary that doesn't sport the word "website" yet. And Google Translate only offers "Webseite" with no alternatives.

Comment: @MrLister, the thing is that "Webseite" literally translates to "web page" - thus a single page, not a whole website. http://dict.leo.org/ende/?lang=de&from=fxdesktop&search=website So, German options for website would be "Website", "Webangebot", "Netzplatz". The first being the obvious loanword (as seen often in comp.science)."Webangebot" mixing two languages and "Netzplatz", well, might be technically correct but sounds somewhat artificial.

Comment: I found some places where they used "Stelle". Not very many though...

Comment: Note that LEO is not really authoritative on any language.
Being German, having studied and worked in Web-related areas, I have certainly never come across "Netzplatz", and "Webangebot" might have appeared occasionally, but I can not imagine it without reference to or implication of a commercial or public entity behind the site - whose site is an "offer"/"Angebot" of them (possibly amongst other things). People say "Webseite" or even just "Seite" referring to even whole domains all the time, of course the false friend "Seite"/"site" doesn't help in this regard.

Comment: *Internet-Präsenz* or *-Angebot* are further terms- may be a little highbrow..

Comment: @MrLister Another common German term for website is "Homepage". Like "Webseite", it's wrong from a technical point of view, but this doesn't keep people from using it. A nice but non-colloquial alternative is "Internetauftritt" or "Webauftritt". "Auftritt" is more general than "Angebot" and similar to "Präsenz". Personally, I mostly use "Website" without translation.

Answer (score 5):

Of course it depends on the exact context.  In many contexts in software localisation, *about* is translated, literally, into *about us* or into *about [product/company]*.  (This is true for many other languages too, like Russian, Serbo-Croatian, Armenian, etc.  However into Spanish it’s also often *Información*.)

Go to https://www.facebook.com/ and https://www.google.co.uk/?hl=en (in an incognito window), then switch languages while watching the *About* link in the footer.  https://airbnb.de/about has one menu with *Über* and one with *Über uns* (*About us*), but the the former strikes me as a compromise in order to preserve menu aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

Zwar stimme ich Problemofficer zu, dass *über* seltsam klingt, ohne Zusatz um was, aber ich sehe nicht, dass dies im Englischen anders wäre. Der Kürze wegen hat sich wohl beides eingebürgert, und inzwischen ist beides gängig und wird auch verstanden, wohl zu spät sich eine harmonischere Lösung auszudenken.

Könnte man die Zeit zurückdrehen würde ich für *Hintergrund* votieren.