# Alternative für den Ausdruck "über mich"

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-request

Ich suche eine Alternative für den Ausdruck "über mich".

Es ist für einen Menüeintrag auf einer Website. Ich finde es fantasielos, überall im Web diesen Menüeintrag zu finden.

Leider hat es sich herausgestellt, dass dies gar nicht so einfach ist, auch wenn man einen anständigen Wortschatz besitzt.

Irgendwelche Ideen?

**Edit**

Die Ausdrücke "Porträt" & "Profil" kämen in Frage.

Comment: Siehe auch: [What is the German equivalent of “about” (as in “about this site”)](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26182/what-is-the-german-equivalent-of-about-as-in-about-this-site)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich bin eigentlich dagegen, "Über mich" zu ersetzen. Wie du sagst ist es gewöhnlich, diesen Ausdruck zu finden. Den Leuten gefällt es nicht, was ungewöhnliches, unerwartetes zu finden. Es stört ein bisschen. Kennst du das Buch "Don't make me think" von Steve Krug?

Deshalb würde ich "Über mich" lassen.

Wenn du trotzdem eine Alternative suchst, dann kannst du vielleicht "Wer ich bin" benutzen.

Comment: Du hast mich überzeugt. Grade im Web ist es ratsamer, bei geläufigen Begriffen zu bleiben, nicht zuletzt für Themen wie SEO & Adwords

Answer (score 3):

Eine andere Variante wäre z.B. "Biografie" oder dein Name als Link.

Answer (score 3):

- *Wer?*; *Wer steckt dahinter?*; *Wer ist Daenu?*; *Daenu?*; *Daenu*
- *Über den Autor*; *Über Daenu*
- *Ich*
- *Info*; *Autoreninfo*
- *Vita*
- *Kontakt*
- *Impressum*

Answer (score 2):

Eine weitere Möglichkeit: "Zur Person" oder "Persönliches".